# What are the conditions creating a chat room after commenting?

Tags: discussion, chat

There are chat rooms created after comment chains on Stack Overflow. I'm wondering what is the condition for it to happen?

I've read meta posts like [How do I turn comments into a chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291524/how-do-i-turn-comments-into-a-chat-room)

But they are from users, is there any official documentation on this?

Comment: MSE is the official documentation. Content and guidance is written by users like you and me.

Comment: So are you suggesting that although SO developers had some rule, we only know that by inspection and experience?

Comment: Sometimes, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are offered the option to move the comments on a post to a chatroom when two users have exchanged at least 3 messages each under a post (so, after a minimum of 6 comments).

Comments on a post can only be moved to a chatroom once, but the option is offered whenever the comments qualify, until it's clicked on.

Do know that it doesn't matter if the users involved have [chat privileges (available at 20 reputation)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat), or not. Even if you can't chat, you still get the option to move comments to chat (where you won't be able to participate with < 20 reputation).

Not all features are documented "officially". The SE dev team builds and deploys new versions of the software into production every workday, either with bug fixes and/or new features. Sometimes, this is accompanied by a Meta post (most often on the [Uber-Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)), but mostly, the regulars notice something is changed / added and verify in chat with SE staff when the users are unsure if it's a feature or a bug. After confirmation, the community members document the feature:

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

See also [announcements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements)